# Spacing divs from database

Tags: mysql, css, html

Website [here](http://cambridge.guestvibe.com).

I am pulling values from the database and displaying them in the right hand box out of the two boxes on the image. There are four values in the middle: price, queue jump, deal 1, and deal 2. My problem is that not every offer includes all 4. However, there is a spacing gap where the div has its margins where the value would have been. Other than putting the div inside the database field, is there anything else I can do to avoid this?

Here is my Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://cambridge.guestvibe.com/wp-content/themes/cambridge/eventinfo.php",
            data:  $('#club').serialize(),
            success: function(data) {
                $('#rightbox_inside').html('<h2><div class="tagnospacing">' + $('#club').val() + '</div></h2><p><div class="tagnospacing">' + data[0].day + '</div></p><hr><p><div class="tag">' + data[0].entry + '</div></p><p><div class="tag">' + data[0].queuejump + '</div></p><p><div class="tag">' + data[0].special + '</div></p><p><div class="tag">' + data[0].special2 + '</div></p><p><div class="tag">' + data[0].closing + '</div></p><hr><p><div id="caveat">All offers subject to availability</div></p>');
                },
            dataType: "json"
        });
    });

    $('#club').change(function(event) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://cambridge.guestvibe.com/wp-content/themes/cambridge/eventinfo.php",
            data:  $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(data) {
                $('#rightbox_inside').hide().html('<h2><div class="tagnospacing">' + $('#club').val() + '</div></h2><p><div class="tagnospacing">' + data[0].day + ', ' + data[0].doors + '</div></p><hr><p><div class="tag">' + data[0].entry + '</div></p><p><div class="tag">' + data[0].queuejump + '</div></p><p><div class="tag">' + data[0].special + '</div></p><p><div class="tag">' + data[0].special2 + '</div></p><p><div class="tag">' + data[0].closing + '</div><hr><p><div id="caveat">All offers subject to availability</div></p>').fadeIn('500');
                },
            dataType: "json"
        });

    });

</script>
```

Comment: You should try and include all relevant information within the question itself, rather than relying on external sources that may not stick around for the future.

Comment: Don't mix your data with your presentation code.

That said, a code snippet would help understand what you're doing.

Comment: What method are you using to retrieve the records? If it's just PHP all you have to do is make the output of the divs optional with if statements.

Comment: I'm using PHP with AJAX so the actual printing is happening in Javascript.

Comment: if the fetched field is not empty, echo the divs. Otherwise don't - assuming PHP.